# android how to find similar string in an arraylist

Tags: android, string, search, arraylist

I have a list and show it in a recycler view.but I want use a search view and search all names that is in list.I want when I search "ab" every names that contain "ab" display in my recyclerview.I can do this with query and use "like" but I dont know how can do it without query and search in a string list

Comment: You have to show some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//add a text change listener to the textview and keep passing the new search string to the following function

//array of data strings
private ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList();
//initalise your array here

//reesults array
private ArrayList<String> resultsArray = new ArrayList();

private void searchFor(String data){ 
   resultsArray.clear();
   //notifiy adapter
   for(int i=0; i<dataArray.size(); i++){
      String unitString = dataArray.get(i);
      if(unitString.contains(data)){
         resultsArray.add(unitString);
         //notifiy adapter
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `contains` method of the String class which takes another String as an argument.

```
String test = "dfbab":

System.out.println(test.contains("ab")); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented it on a project of mine and I used something like this on my `Adapter` :

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    mListFiltered = mList;
                } else {
                    List<Object> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Object item : mList) {
                        if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) {
                            filteredList.add(item);
                        }
                    }

                    mListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mListFiltered = (ArrayList<Object>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

That's a sample, you can follow this example to do what you want [`android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/`](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/)

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate the whole list and check the query for every element.

Practically it would be like this:

```
for (String element:array) {
        if (element.contains(query)){
            //add element to result box
        }
    }
```